# Can elasticsearch return multiple value fields in a single facet?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to create a facet such that I can essentially return two values for one key.

For instance, I am attempting to retrieve both an amount and schedule properties of an object. I attempted to use a computed value script, but the calculations that have to be done using the two objects are date based, and require an external library to perform them.

Basically, something along the lines of:

```
"theFacet": {
      "terms_stats": {
        "key_field": "someKeyProbablyADate",
        "value_field": "amount",
        "value_field": "simpleSchedule"
      }
    }
```

Workarounds are also appreciated. Perhaps some way to return a new dynamic object with both fields?

Comment: Can we see the script that you tried and where you got with it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to pre-process your data before you index it into a single field, then facet on that.

Something among the line of a single string containing key#amount#schedule

Then when you get the faceting results back you can split it up again and run whatever logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining different fields with a `script` element. For example:

```
"facets": {
  "facet-name": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "some-field",
      "script": "_source['another-field'] + '/' + term
    }
  }
}
```